# How do I get the number of frames in a video on command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, video, ffmpeg, batch

I am trying to get the number of frames in a video with ffprobe on windows, but it returns N/A.

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=nb_frames -of default^=nokey^=1:noprint_wrappers^=1 "1.ts" 2^>^&1') do set "frames=%%I" echo %frames%
```

I found a piece of code that is supposed to be able to get the number of frames in these situations, but it was written for Linux and I am not sure how to change it to work on windows.

```
ffmpeg -nostats -i "video.mp4" -vcodec copy -f rawvideo -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep frame | awk '{split($0,a,"fps")}END{print a[1]}' | sed 's/.*= *//'
```

Can someone please help me get the number of frames through ffmpeg when ffprobe returns N/A? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "1.ts"
```